# How to control output voltage on a Buck Converter

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, switching-regulator

I'm fairly new to electronics and I have copied the Buck Converter ([LM2678](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2678.pdf)) in the picture attached to convert 24V to 5V. After trying it I have actually converted 24V to 9V and my question is if I have done something wrong or if the schematic is wrong? The output voltage is apparently controlled with the two resistors at Vout although I can't seem to figure out how that works, so if anyone could explain that to me I would also really appreciate it, as it would help me troubleshoot!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that those two resistors are 3.16kΩ  and 1kΩ in your actual circuit?

Comment: As @BenceKaulics says, check the resistors - chances are the values are not correct. For example, if the 3.16K was actually 6.65K (80B marking, or blue-blue-green-brown-brown)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the problem is that you are testing it with no load. place a 100 ohm resistor at the output and verify if the voltage is ok. if this is not the problem maybe you have a ground problem because of long wires or other assembly troubles. verify if the voltage between feedback and ground is about 1.25 V if it is different try to find why.

Comment: Hi I have tried it with a load and the problem remains the same! Do you know how the resistor values effect the voltage?

Comment: Datasheet [page 14](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2678.pdf) at step 2, there is the equation you need. \$ V_{out} = V_{FB} \times (1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1}) \$ where \$  V_{FB} = 1.21V\$

Comment: From what you write the output should be around 5 V but you should verify with an ohmmeter the resistor values and the voltage at the 1k resistor. Another problem could arise from the 1000 uF capacitor that could cause instability. Try removing it with the 100 ohm load. Eventually measure the AC output voltage, not only the DC.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error amplifier in the regulator that controlls the pulse width of the signal
 that turns the output mosfet on and off.  The datasheet should tell you what that is.  You use the resistors divider so that  voltage fedback to the control loop is the "error voltage"  when the voltage is at the output level you are trying to achieve.